# CSRF protection on GET methods using csurf module

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

I have this GET endpoint but I'm not sure how to call it. I always get invalid csrf token. My POST endpoint is working great. I don't have any issues. I only have issue with GET endpoint.

```
const csrf = require('csurf');

router.route('/sessioncount')
  .get(csrf({ ignoreMethods: [] }), (req, res, next) => {
    sess = req.session;
    if (sess.authenticated) {
      if (sess.views) {
        sess.views++;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.write('<p>Session views: ' + sess.views + '</p>');
        res.end();
      } else {
        sess.views = 1;
        res.end('Welcome, you are logged in!');
      }
    } else {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      res.write('<p>You are not allowed to view this page. Please <a href="/api/form">log in</a></p>');
      res.end();
    }
  })
```

I'm calling it this way but I'm guessing it only

```
http://localhost:31337/api/sessioncount?csrf=qudszjrT-mQ5uu4qXrQXI7C_NJYlXXUIdKB0
http://localhost:31337/api/sessioncount?_csrf=qudszjrT-mQ5uu4qXrQXI7C_NJYlXXUIdKB0
http://localhost:31337/api/sessioncount?csrfToken=qudszjrT-mQ5uu4qXrQXI7C_NJYlXXUIdKB0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing this

```
// const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
const csrfProtection = csrf();
```